# How does this backdoor work?

Tags: wordpress, backdoor

I just found that one of my wordpress websites included backdoor (my guess).

As I see now, the same file on server is different than original on my laptop drive. So I think my website is already infected. Can you help me clean that up?

Sorry I can't put the code here as I am new and code is big and don't know how to import. You can see it here: [Backdoor](https://pastebin.com/yARx7ZbB)

Any Help Appreciated!!!

Comment: If you have a clean backup, restore from that.

Answer (score 4):

This is knows as **Wp-vcd Malware**. For full analysis you can check [here](https://medium.com/@cirku17/wp-vcd-malware-analysis-7c5dbaad89c3).

For hardening Wordpress check [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress), and if you ask yourself, what should you do when your website is hacked - click [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked).

For removing that particular malware follow [this](https://github.com/rakshitshah94/wordpress-wp-vcd-malware-attack-solution#wordpress-wp-vcd-malware-attack-solution).

More from IBM X-Force Exchange:

> Malicious code injection inside a wordpress theme's functions.php and
>   wp-includes editing posts content.
>
> Injected files:
>
> ```
> wp-vcd.php
> class.wp.php
> ```
>
> Edited files:
>
> ```
> functions.php
> post.php
> ```
>
> Analysis
>
> https://medium.com/@cirku17/wp-vcd-malware-analysis-7c5dbaad89c3
>
> Repository
>
> https://github.com/CirKu17/wp-vcd-malware-sample

**Keep in mind that this may be updated version of malware, so I didn't go through all the source - my suggestion for you is to backup your website and database from clean backups.**